# Datepicker/Timepicker adapts to rotation change

Tags: android, datepicker, timepicker

I have a Timepicker and Datepicker but whenever I change my screen rotation, it glitches and only half of the dialog appears onscreen. I would like the Datepicker/Timepicker to adapt to rotation changes.

DropBox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nrqievn3u1tbzv0/Screenshot_2015-09-09-22-11-05.png?dl=0

Comment: can you provide some screenshots?

Comment: @agamov I would have done but I don't have enough reputation

Comment: you can just put them on dropbox and post the links

Comment: @agamov added the link

Comment: Maybe put datepicker and timepicker in a horizontal scrollview layout, or disable the screen rotation, and make a separate layout for default landscape devices such as tablets.